# Find the Missing Element by iterating dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

I'm trying to find the missing element but I just keep running into issues
the below is my code. It seems it doesn't iterate through the dictionary

```
def finder(arr1,arr2):
    if len(arr1) == len(arr2):
        return 

    target = {}
    for k in arr1:
        if k in target:
            target[k] +=1
        else:
            target[k] = 1
    print (target)
    for k in arr2:
        if k in target:
            target[k] -= 1
        else:
            target[k] = 1
    print (target)

    for k,v in target.items():
        if v != 0
            print(k ,"is the missing number")

#         else:
#            return
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you are not just summing the arrays and then subtracting. The difference will be the missing number

Comment: This code gives me `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Is that what you're getting on your machine?

Comment: By the way, this code is missing `:`: `if v != 0` should be `if v != 0:`. When this is fixed your code works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two dicts (which can't have repeated keys by definition)

```
def finder(first_dict, second_dict):
    return set(first_dict) - set(second_dict)
```

or, if you have lists with possible repeated elements:

```
def finder(first_list, second_list):
    return (collections.Counter(first_list) - collections.Counter(second_list)).keys()
```

Comment: Doesn't work if the numbers in the arrays are not unique

Comment: @DeepSpace array? They said it is a dict

Comment: OP tries to find the missing number between two arrays/lists. OP just happen to use a dict

Comment: @DeepSpace added the answer for that too